# Regex to get string between number and underscore C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i'm tryng make a regex to get the string between some number and underscore, for example:

I have **CP_01Ags_v5**, so I need a regex to match just `Ags`. another example could be **CP_13Hgo_v5** and match `Hgo`.

Some idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use look-arounds to match just the string between the digits and the underscore e.g.

```
(?<=\d)[A-Za-z]+(?=_)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rOMkq4/1)

In C# (note the need to escape the `\` in the regex):

```
String s = @"CP_01Ags_v5 CP_13Hgo_v5";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, "(?<=\\d)[A-Za-z]+(?=_)");
while (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Output

```
Ags
Hgo
```

Answer (score 3):

Based off the examples and matches you are describing. You want something along the lines of.

```
[0-9]+(.*)[_]
```

to break it down. 
The regex looking for any number that shows up one or more times then matches everything after the number(s) up until the [_] underscore.

The downfall is this assumes the examples you provided are similar. If your example is

```
CP_13Hgo_v5asdf_
```

then it will match

```
Hgo_v5asdf
```

---

**if you have other possible findings then you want the non-greedy version of this regex.**

```
[0-9]+(.*?)[_]
```

this will cause two groups to be found in this example

```
CP_13Hgo_v5asdf_
```

will find the following groups:

```
Hgo
```

and

```
asdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always at least two characters and there are *no* other strings of at least two characters, then you can apply the following:

```
var text = "CP_01Ags_v5";
var x = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<!^)[A-Za-z]{2,}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex `Group`:

```
(?<leftPart>_\d{2})(?<YourTarget>[a-zA-Z])(?<rightPart>_[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})
```

`C#`:

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<leftPart>_\d{2})(?<YourTarget>[a-zA-Z])(?<rightPart>_[a-zA-Z0-9]{2})");

/*
* Loop
* To get value of group you want
*/
foreach (Match item in re.Matches("CP_01Ags_v5 CP_13Hgo_v5,"))
{
        Console.WriteLine(" Match: " + item.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(" Your Target you want: " + item.Groups["YourTarget"]);        
}
```